# I want to pick out one column of the DataFrame but the result is automatically ordered by values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I just need one column of my dateframe, but in the original order. When I take it off, it is sorted by the values, and I can't understand why. I tried different ways to pick out one column but all the time it was sorted by the values.

this is my code:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('/data.csv', sep=';')
longti = data.iloc[:,4]
```

Comment: Your approach should work. Could you post some example data that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To return the first `Column` your function should work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2,3,4,5,6], B=['A','B','C','D','E','F']))
df = df.iloc[:,0]
```

Out:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
```

If you want to return the second `Column` you can use the following:

```
df = df.iloc[:,1]
```

Out:

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
```